# print image on odt file using php

Tags: php, image, odt

I have a php page which outputs an .odt file printing data retrieved from a database.
I use the method below to create the .odt file:

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text');
```

The only problem I am experiencing is with `<img>` tag. The following command is ignored and no pictures appear on my .odt file:

```
<img src="/path_to_images/my_image.png">
```

I have tried using both the relative and the absolute paths to point to the image.

Comment: The `header()` command only tells the browser that you're going to serve a ODT file. How are you generating the ODT file itself? Using any specific library?

Comment: Not really.           `header('Content-Type: application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="my_file.odt"');`       that's all I do.

Comment: Ale, you still didn't show us the code you're using to create the ODT file itself. Are you sending plain HTML and expect it to be opened as ODT..? Some other method..?

Comment: Exactly. And it works (except for the images). Are specific libraries recommended?

Comment: Try using the full URL for the image, eg: `<img src="http://example.com/path/image.png"></img>`. I've just tried it locally and it seems to be working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The answer suggested by uri2x worked just fine.
In conclusion, the full URL enables the image to appear on the .odt file:

```
<img src="http://example.com/path/image.png">
```